# File Not Found Error in Python 3

Tags: python, python-3.x, indexing, filesystems

I'm a beginner at Python so please help! The file is not being read. I'm trying to open the file so that I make a Btree out of the content. I'm running Python on windows using Canopy IDE.
It says

```
FileNotFoundError                         Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-8-e4d1c59d96ad> in <module>()
----> 1 file = open("IN.txt","r") FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'IN.txt'
```

Here is the code

```
def main():

    B = BTree(154757)
    print('==========Loading==========')
    with open('IN.txt', 'r') as f:
        for line in f:
            word = line.split("\t")
            B.insert((hash(word[2]), int(word[1]), word[2]))
    print('==========Loaded==========')
```

Comment: The error says it all... make you sure when you are opening the file you either 1) work in the same directory, 2) include the full file path when using `open()`

Answer (score 1):

The File is probably not where the script is looking for it. If you don't specify a complete file path, then it looks in the current working directory. You can check the current directory by

```python
import os
print(os.getcwd())
```